# How to change the label and deitalicize expex example?

Tags: formatting, linguistics, cjk, expex

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newenvironment{korean}{%
  \CJKfamily{mj}}{}
\usepackage{expex}

\begin{document}

\ex[glhangstyle=none]
\let\\=\textscp
\begingl
\gla
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{}\begin{korean}이러한\end{korean}\end{CJK*} \begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{}\begin{korean}작용을\end{korean}\end{CJK*} \begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{}\begin{korean}발휘하기\end{korean}\end{CJK*}  \begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{}\begin{korean}위해서는\end{korean}\end{CJK*} , \begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{}\begin{korean}각각\end{korean}\end{CJK*} 0.005\% \begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{}\begin{korean}이상\end{korean}\end{CJK*} \begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{}\begin{korean}함유하는\end{korean}\end{CJK*} \begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{}\begin{korean}것이\end{korean}\end{CJK*} \begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{}\begin{korean}바람직하다\end{korean}\end{CJK*}  //
\glb
such reaction to-achieve so-as-to , each 0.005\% or-more to-contain it preferably .
//
\glft
`It is preferable to have 0.005\% or more of each [chemical] so as to achieve the reaction.'//
\endgl
\xe

\end{document}
```

And it outputs:

[image]

**How do I change the numerical label to a string label, e.g. instead of `(1)` to something like `Example 1:`?**

**How do I deitalicize the first row?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the format of the example number you need to specify the `exnoformat` hook.  To format the lines of the gloss correctly you should use the `everygl` hooks provided by ExPex. For the first line you use `everygla=`  By default it is set to `\it`.  But you can't use environments in these hooks, you must use switches. So I would recommend *not* using CJKutf8 but instead using xeCJK, which will make your input much, much simpler.  Here's your example. Compile with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Gulim}
\usepackage{expex}


\begin{document}

\ex[glhangstyle=none,everygla={\upshape},exnoformat=Example X]
\let\\=\textscp
\begingl
\gla
이러한 작용을 발휘하기  위해서는 , 각각 0.005\% 이상 함유하는 것이 바람직하다  //
\glb
such reaction to-achieve so-as-to , each 0.005\% or-more to-contain it preferably .
//
\glft
`It is preferable to have 0.005\% or more of each [chemical] so as to achieve the reaction.'//
\endgl
\xe

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good solution, but one way to deitalicize the first line is to wrap each word with `\emph{}`. You have to do each word in turn, otherwise the glosses get messed up. Obviously this is time-consuming, and I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but I've provided it in case it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try: `\lingset{everygla={\emph}}`. That did the job for me.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Gulim}
\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{everygla={\emph}}

\begin{document}

\ex[glhangstyle=none,everygla={\upshape},exnoformat=Example X]
\let\\=\textscp
\begingl
\gla
이러한 작용을 발휘하기  위해서는 , 각각 0.005\% 이상 함유하는 것이 바람직하다  //
\glb
such reaction to-achieve so-as-to , each 0.005\% or-more to-contain it preferably .
//
\glft
`It is preferable to have 0.005\% or more of each [chemical] so as to achieve the reaction.'//
\endgl
\xe

\end{document}
```